# Getting a value/relative url from an anchor tag in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some HTML like this:

```
<span class="fetchSeries"><a href="sma10">10</a></span>
```

I want to get the value "sma10," but the href attribute becomes an absolute path when I try to reference it.  Is there a way to get the relative path of the anchor tag?

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Bind a custom function to click() for any hyperlink within a span class="fetchSeries" tag.
2. Extract a value that is unique for that link (eg. sma10).

Answer (score 3):

If the unique value isn't really a href, you might use data attributes:

**HTML**

```
<span class="fetchSeries"><a href="#" data-myvalue="sma10">10</a></span>
```

**JavaSCript**

```
$('.fetchSeries a').click(function() {
   var myval = $(this).data('myvalue');
});
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/data

Answer (score 1):

Use thic [code](http://jsfiddle.net/WZELq/):

```
$(function(){
    var v = $('.fetchSeries a').attr('href');
    alert(v);
});
```

Comment: I will try this.  The problem is that when I was looking at "href" in firebug it was showing the absolute url, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer my answer this stackoverflow post: 
[Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element/23936529#23936529)

Or using pure javascript

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
```

from https://gist.github.com/ldong/9735bcd2d3eca8c1038b

Answer (score 0):

You could use getAttribute to get the relative value of the href as long as the value of the href is relative like in the example.

i.e.
`document.getElementByID("theLink").getAttribute("href");`