# How to trigger click event on href element

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, hyperlink, click

I'm trying to trigger click event on hyperlink with jQuery like the way below. Hyperlink does not have any id but it does have css class:

```
$(document).ready(function () {  
  $('.cssbuttongo').trigger('click'); 
});
```

The function above is not working. This is the hyperlink:

```
<a href="hyperlinkurl" class="cssbuttongo">hyperlink anchor</a>
```

Comment: As a class can be applied to several elements in the DOM, it not seems a good idea trigger a click on them.

Comment: NomikOS you are very right about that but i checked that whether any other element uses this css class :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element/28015837#28015837

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I do not have factual evidence to prove this but I already ran into this issue. It seems that triggering a click() event on an `<a>` tag doesn't seem to behave the same way you would expect with say, a input button.

The workaround I employed was to set the location.href property on the window which causes the browser to load the request resource like so:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      var href = $('.cssbuttongo').attr('href');
      window.location.href = href; //causes the browser to refresh and load the requested url
   });
});
```

Edit:

I would make a js fiddle but the nature of the question intermixed with how jsfiddle uses an iframe to render code makes that a no go.

Comment: this is the correct answer. thank you :)  i also noticed that click on href does not work.

Comment: @MonsterMMorpg Keep in mind that this does not result in the browser believing that it is direct user action. So use wisely =D

Comment: Shouldn't it be var href = $('.cssbuttongo').attr('href');

Comment: This ignores the possibility that the link also has an `onclick` event. Just do `$('.cssbuttongo')[0].click()` to properly simulate a click in its entirety.

Comment: Actually it works only on the complete href. Since I couldn't put code here, please read my answer to this post.

Answer (score 235):

The native DOM method does the right thing:

```
$('.cssbuttongo')[0].click();
                  ^
              Important!
```

This works regardless of whether the `href` is a URL, a fragment (e.g. `#blah`) or even a `javascript:`.

Note that this calls the DOM `click` method instead of the jQuery `click` method (which is very incomplete and completely ignores `href`).

Comment: @LinDong: Please provide a link to a JsFiddle that contains the text `[0].click()` which does not work as expected.

Comment: @Timwi, I meant to say the first one `$('.cssbuttongo').click(); // ignores href!` won't guarantee to work. The latter one will always work, because using index [0] will make jQuery Object to regular JS Object which is exactly the same one browser uses. @Wei Liu

Comment: @LinDong: That’s exactly what this answer is saying!

Comment: @LinDong OK, I see where the confusion was. You were looking at my example of what doesn't work and saying that it doesn't work. I've removed that example; it wasn't even needed in the first place.

Comment: @trainoasis You sure about "target"? [Seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/h77f74LL/2/). Haven't tested "download".

Comment: hmm, didn't work in my case, that is strange indeed. download attr in html5 supported browsers did not fire as expected. unfortunately

Comment: `click()` is a jQuery function, while `$('.cssbuttongo')[0]` won't return a jQuery object. This should throw an error. I don't know how it's working for so many people. The correct syntax should be this: `$($('.cssbuttongo')[0]).click()`

Comment: @AdilMalik It works because jquery is not the only thing that has a click() method. This code calls the non-jquery click() method, it's a native DOM thing.

Comment: @romkyns I see. But I just tried it. It's giving me `undefined` error. Must be something wrong on my end, because many people are testifying that your solution is working for them :-)

Comment: @Timwi  I provide jsfiddle in here: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/3gv90od5/

Comment: It works! In some case someone looking for a code I'll add this $(' #.cssbuttongo a').first()[0].click(); if you want to click the first child :)

Answer (score 34):

<sub>In addition to romkyns's [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762745/2680216).. here is some relevant documentation/examples.</sub>

---

DOM Elements [have a native `.click()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click).

> The `HTMLElement.click()` method simulates a mouse click on an element.
>
> When click is used, it also fires the element's click event which will bubble up to elements higher up the document tree (or event chain) and fire their click events too. **However, bubbling of a click event will not cause an `<a>` element to initiate navigation as if a real mouse-click had been received.** [(mdn reference)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click)

Relevant [W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-2651361).

---

A few examples..

- You can access a specific DOM element from a jQuery object: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/3649009w/)

  ```
    $('a')[0].click();
  ```
- You can use the [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) method to retrieve a DOM element from a jQuery object: [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/g8La2mzL/)

  ```
    $('a').get(0).click();
  ```
- As expected, you can select the DOM element and call the [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) method. [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/m8dc018e/)

  ```
    document.querySelector('a').click();
  ```

It's worth pointing out that jQuery is *not* required to trigger a native [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click) event.

Answer (score 4):

Triggering a click via JavaScript will not open a hyperlink. This is a security measure built into the browser.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1421584/901048) for some workarounds, though.

Comment: I don't think so..
BECAUSE : **I FOUND ITS WORKING LIKE THIS** .. Follow the [jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/8AVau/2/)

Comment: @CodyDmd that's still a user-triggered click event taking place. Not the same thing as OP's original question.

Comment: @CodyDmd It seems that `[0]` is important in your fiddle

Comment: What vulnerability does that protect against, exactly?

Comment: @romkyns Triggering downloads, or SEO click fraud.

Comment: @CodyDmd Look at your JSFiddle `target="_blank"`

Comment: @Blazemonger i updated the jsfiddle, thanks for your info. is this the way OP is asking?
http://jsfiddle.net/8AVau/60/

Comment: @mk1 i just added target attribute for the demonstration purpose.. please check it out the updated jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/8AVau/60/

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean, Blazemonger, because there is no such protection against downloads or SEO click fraud in Firefox, nor Chrome, nor IE11. In other words, both the first and the second sentence of your answer [are false](http://jsfiddle.net/4kAxm/9/).

Answer (score 3):

Just want to let you guys know, the accepted answer doesn't always work.

Here's an example it will fail.

if `<href='/list'>`

```
href = $('css_selector').attr('href')
"/list"
href = document.querySelector('css_selector').href
"http://localhost/list"
```

or you could append the href you got from jQuery to this

```
href = document.URL +$('css_selector').attr('href');
```

or  jQuery way

```
href = $('css_selector').prop('href')
```

Finally, invoke it to change the browser current page's url

```
window.location.href = href
```

or pop it out using `window.open(url)`

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xj2wD/)'s an example in JSFiddle.

Comment: So you're saying this doesn't work if you change it to `$('css_selector')[0].click()`? It works in [this JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kAxm/5/)...

Comment: For the record, it wasn't me who downvoted; I think there may be something here and I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @romkyns, Of course, it's going to work after you extract from jQuery elements using[0] (It becomes pure JS), I meant to say `$('.cssbuttongo').click();` won't work because it only gives whatever the value of href, instead of the URL of the browser uses. Sorry about the misleading comments.

Comment: @LinDong: If you **know** that `[0].click()` works, why does your answer not mention that?

Comment: `location.href` accepts relative paths, so using `/list` will automatically prepend the current domain. So it does work.

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue how to click a button, instead of a link. It did not success in the methods .trigger('click') or [0].click(), and I did not know why. At last, the following was working for me:

```
$('#elementid').mousedown();
```