# Jquery trigger click after ajax call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax call and at the end of it I'm setting `href` for anchor tag and want to click it but am unable to do so. Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <a id="hypSendEmail">email</a>
</div>

$("body").on("click", "#btnPopulateEmails", function () {
        var $form = $("#btnPopulateEmails").parents('form');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            async: true,
            data: $form.serialize()
        }).done(function (data) {
            var json = data,
            obj = JSON.parse(json);
            if (obj.MessageType == "success") {
                $("#hypSendEmail").attr('href', obj.MessageLink);
                $("#hypSendEmail").trigger("click");
                //$("#hypSendEmail").click();
                $.colorbox.close();
            }
            if (obj.MessageContent != null) {
                //do something else
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I believe I have to somehow use `.on` function to trigger that click maybe? Please help. My purpose is to populate hyperlink with mailto & click it automatically. I tried doing this on code behing using `Process.Start()` & `Response.Redirect()`, but both failed, so now I'm trying my luck here. It does populate `href` tag on my anchor tag, but just doesn't click it.

Comment: Maybe would be better use `window.location.href = obj.MessageLink;` ?

Comment: Use window.location.href = obj.MessageLink

Comment: window.location.href works. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: you don't need `JSON.parse()` at all in jquery ajax requests if you just add `dataType: 'json'` to the settings, btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked thanks to Alexander & Ragnar comments:

```
window.location.href = obj.MessageLink;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a possible duplicate of [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element).

Jquery trigger is only triggering handlers and not the native behavior of the anchor tag.  Instead of using jquery.trigger, use the native DOM "click" instead.

Change this line:

```
$("#hypSendEmail").trigger("click");
```

To this instead:

```
$("#hypSendEmail")[0].click();
```

Hope that helps!