# Select RadioBox on MouseOver?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to create a form of radioboxes where you can select them simply by mousing over without any clicking.  I can't figure out how to do this, my current code doesn't work.  Any ideas why? Thanks!

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.my_checkboxes').mouseover(function () {
                $(this).find('boxclass').click();

            });
</script>
```

Comment: What a radiobox? Do you mean radio button or checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the logic explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element/28015837#28015837), you would have to use the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.my_checkboxes').mouseover(function () {
        $(this).find('boxclass')[0].click();
    });
});
```

DOM Elements [have a native `.click()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.click). You need to access the element rather than the jQuery object in order to trigger a programmatic click event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".cb").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).prop("checked", "checked");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="cb" name="test">
<input type="radio" class="cb" name="test">
```