# simulate a click on link using jquery not working

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#foo").on("click", function (event) {
  alert($(this).text());
});

$("#foo").trigger("click");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="foo" class="fancybox.iframe btn btn-primary" href="addDepartment.jsp" >Next Page</a>
```

when the page is loaded alert box shows the "Next Page" , but fancybox doesn't open up .
If I physically click on that button(link) then it is working fine.

Comment: Give jsfiddle or html

Comment: What exactly you want ONClick on Href ? Or Linking via Href ? Decide it first!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element

This may help.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com He wants it to run the jQuery click handler, then perform the default action of following the link.

Comment: @DeepakPandey , I gave you answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    $("#foo").on("click", function (event) {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
    $("#foo").trigger("click");
   $( "#foo").unbind( "click" );

</script>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apdn0ugr/1/)**