# jQuery Click specific item

Tags: jquery, list, click

```
<a class="example" href="https://example.com/index.php">hellau</a>
<a class="example" href="https://example1.com/index.php">hellau1</a>
<a class="example" href="https://example2.com/index.php">hellau2</a>
```

Need to get and go to second href somehow.

```
$('.example')[1].click();
```

doesn't work sticks to one random link until entry is removed

```
var link = $(".example");
link.click();
window.location.href = link[1].attr("href");
```

doesn't work either

Any way to make it click specific text part or something along those lines?

Text and links are dynamic

Comment: To be clear, what do you want to accomplish? Click on first link causing redirection to second link `href` or Trigger a click on second link?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element)

Comment: trigger a click on second link, in this example. But it could be any link max up to 50 random links

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `trigger()`

```
$('.example').eq(1).trigger('click');
```

Alternative way

```
$('.example').eq(1).on('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

***Need to get and go to second href somehow.***

You are trying to trigger the click event of second anchor element. However it will not trigger the default action of redirecting to href. You will need to get the href of second element and then set windows href location to it.

Like this:

```
window.location.href = $(".example:eq(1)").attr('href');
```

Comment: `$('.example')[1].click();` Why this doesn't work? Add details in your answer.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you are right. It should work normally.

Comment: @RejithRKrishnan Yeah. That should work. Need to figure out what is the problem there.

Comment: is it possible to pass a variable into eq() ?

Comment: @Yer what kind of value are you thinking about?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element duplicate

Comment: something like in example below

Comment: $('.example').eq(1).trigger('click') but instead of 1 just pass another variable like var linkNumber = somenumber

Comment: did you mean this?

var linkNumber = somenumber
$(".example:eq("+linkNumber +")").trigger('click')

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
$("a.example").click(function(){

      var href = $(this).attr('href');
      window.location.href = href;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example code for what you look :
**Jquery**

```
$("a").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("href"));
});
```