# Trigger click event after parsing html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I can programmatically go to an url, get the response and parse it. But can I trigger the javascript click event of an html element of that response? For example, let's say the response contains an element:

`<div id="test">Click me</div>`

And the page handles the click event like:

`$("#test").on('click'.....` etc.

So, is there a way that I can trigger that event after I get the html response?

Comment: On the client, Only using a bookmarklet or user script

Comment: I'm a little lost on what you're trying to do

Comment: DOM elements have a [native `.click()` method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element/28015837#28015837). Try: `$("#test")[0].click()`.

Comment: You can't do it with client side scripting like javascript I think. You will need to use a server side script to do that with. Look into curl if you use php.

Comment: After hitting your url , use [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) after displaying the content. Haven't tried it . Hope this works out your problem

Comment: _"can programmatically go to an url, get the response and parse it. But can I trigger the javascript click event of an html element of that response?"_ Is `<script>` tag containing `#test` click handler included within parsed response ?

Answer (score 0):

DOM elements have a .click()

So, something like this works:

```
 <body>
    <a href="" id="myLink">Test me!</a>
</body>
```

And then you have this:

```
// basic function to be called
function clickMe() {
  alert("Clicked!");
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // click event handler
  $("#myLink").on('click', function() {
    clickMe();
  });

  // invoke the click
  $("#myLink").click();

});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Will approach cause an infinite recursion of `.click()` handler being called ?

Comment: It does not have to. Of course, depends on the actual code. This was just a quick proof of concept.