# Trigger event on link wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click

Hello guys im building a library, for example i give an atribute to a html element

```
<a href="https://google.com" shc="27">
logout
```

like this one shc="27" which means when the key 27 (ESC) will be clicked on keyboard it will trigger a click on the link but for some reason it denies to click it.
here is my full code:

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    checkElementType(e.which);
});

function checkElementType(shortcutKey){
    var element = $("[shc="+shortcutKey+"]");
    var elementType = element.prop('nodeName');

    switch(elementType){
        case 'A':

            console.log(element);
            console.log('click the link');
            element.trigger('click');
        break;
    }
}
```

here is the fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s8fk88ou/2/)

Comment: Not related to your problem but you should be using [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attributes instead of a custom attribute.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element)

Comment: @Andreas why use data-attribute instead of custom attribute ?

Comment: Because your custom attribute isn't defined in the specification which can have undesirable side effects (now or later). These `data-*` attributes have been specified exactly for this purpose. To have a place to store data and still generate valid HTML5 markup

Comment: Okay thank your for your explanation i thought about using data-shc but than i was lazy to type every time data- , thats why i got rid of it, but ill make sure ill use it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `element.trigger('click');` to `element[0].click()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know what I changed but it works

```
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://google.com" class="shortcut" shc="27">
    logout
  </a>
</body>
</html>

$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log(e.which);
    checkElementType(e.which);
});

function checkElementType(shortcutKey){
    var element = $("[shc="+shortcutKey+"]");
    var elementType = element.prop('nodeName');

    switch(elementType){
        case 'A':
            element.trigger('click');
            console.log(element);
            console.log('click the link');
        break;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s8fk88ou/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.href` attribute to open the link based on `href` attribute of element:

```
window.location.href = element.attr('href');
```

Hope this helps.

---

```js
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
  console.log(e.which);
  checkElementType(e.which);
 });

 function checkElementType(shortcutKey){
  var element = $("[shc="+shortcutKey+"]");
  var elementType = element.prop('nodeName');

  switch(elementType){
   case 'A':
    console.log(element);
    console.log('click the link');
                
                window.location.href = element.attr('href');
                //Or
                //element[0].click();
                //Or
                //element[0].trigger('click');
                
   break;
  }
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com" class="shortcut" shc="27">logout</a>
```

Comment: This works, but there is another problem when i try to trigger a button it wont work

Comment: Which button? i can see just the link tag `<a>`.

Comment: Okay i see, next time care to add all the needed info to the OP, good luck, happy coding.