# Change image when scrolled to a certain div

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll

I added the logo as a background-image and I have 4 divs (#home, #about, #projects, #contact). Now I want to change the logo when the page is scrolled to a certain div, e.g.: when scrolled to **#about** the logo should change to **logo-dark.png** and the **width** should be reduced to **50px**. How can I do this?

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="#home"> </a>
</div>

<div class="content">
    <div id="home">
    </div>
    <div id="about">
    </div>
    <div id="projects">
    </div>
    <div id="contact">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.logo {
    position: absolute;
    height: 65px;
    width: 230px;
    top: 25px;
    left: 0;
}

.logo a{
    background: url('../images/logo.png');
    display: block;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Could you post all of your code? It's not clear what you're asking here.

Comment: I think this could help you...
[onScreen](http://benpickles.github.io/onScreen/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/eu6x72zf/1/

HTML example:

```
<div id="img1">


</div>
<div class="placeholder">

</div>
<a id="anchor-point">scroll to here</a>
```

CSS example:

```
#img1 {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.placeholder {
  height: 900px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
  var targetOffset = $("#anchor-point").offset().top;

  var $w = $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (($w.scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > targetOffset) {
      $('#img1').css({
        "background-image": "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/')"
      });
    } else {
      $('#img1').css({
        "background-image": "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')"
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking into Javascript to achieve your goal.  For example, if you were going to utilize jquery, I would write something similar to this

```
$( "#example" ).click(function() {
  $(".logo").css("background":"url(../pathway/logo.png", "width": "50px");
});
```

This is a very rough example, because there's only so much that you've given to your code. You'll also have to tailor it to your specific scroll needs. I believe these may be able to help you: [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element) , 
https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: OP is asking to trigger at a page location during scroll, not on-click

Comment: Gotcha. I believe I read it wrong/didn't understand at first.   You got it though, in your answer.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it