# Trigger onload, inline javascript event

Tags: javascript, triggers, inline

I've a pop-up that can be called trough a link. The problem is that i need to call it onload, an I can't find a way to do this.

This is the code of the pop-up

```
   <a href="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox/14169a873f72a2%3A14f192411746dc/5636318331666432/"
    target="_blank">Click Here to Subscribe</a>
    <script data-leadbox="14169a873f72a2:14f192411746dc"
    data-url="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox/14169a873f72a2%3A14f192411746dc/5636318331666432/"
    data-config="%7B%7D" type="text/javascript"
    src="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox-1483020619.js">
    </script>
```

I've tried to trigger the "Click Here to Subcribe" in different ways, like the following, without success:

1. [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element)
2. jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#add_redirect").trigger('click');
   });
3. Window.location.href (this open the link but in another page, not as a pop-up)

**UPDATE N.1**
I've bypassed the problem loading the pop-up URL through the `<object>` tag.
I've put the `<object>` inside a Bootstrap modal so it still works like some kind of pop-up.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script data-leadbox="14169a873f72a2:14f192411746dc"
    data-url="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox/14169a873f72a2%3A14f192411746dc/5636318331666432/"
    data-config="%7B%7D" type="text/javascript"
    src="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox-1483020619.js"></script>
<script>
var displayPopup = function(){
 var element = document.getElementById('popUp');
 element.click();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="displayPopup();">
  <a href="https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox/14169a873f72a2%3A14f192411746dc/5636318331666432/" id="popUp"
    target="_blank">Click Here to Subscribe</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

I am using plan JS. When `body` JS object is completely formed or in other words when body's content is completely loaded then `onLoad` event is fired . I wired a `displayPopup` function to this event.

In `displayPopup` function i retrieve the anchor tag and manually click it .

Answer (score 0):

Use this following code

```
jQuery=jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   jQuery("#add_redirect").click(); 
});
```

Comment: Already tried. I assigned the ID to the <a></a> but triggers nothing. Thank you for the answer anyway

Comment: I also tried to remove the code that could create conflict but nothing

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Prashanth Reddy should work if you have jQuery loaded on your page.

For a simple implementation using plain javascript, you'll need to change the target attribute on your  tag to '_self' from '_blank'. This will open the popup in your existing page instead of a new page.

then add the following at the end of the body section of your html:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    document.getElementById('add_redirect').click();
  })();
</script>
```

see here for a working example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/868ujjvf/3/)

If you want to avoid inline script tags, you'll need to add an event listener to your javascript code. Here is a good starting point for how to do that:

[plain js equivalent to jquery $.ready](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9899701/3014335)

Comment: Using just this line:
"document.getElementById('add_redirect').click();"
triggers the link, but it opens a new page at the following link, instead showing a pop-up.
 "https://sloways.leadpages.co/leadbox 14169a873f72a2%3A14f192411746dc/5636318331666432/"

Thank you