# Why is trigger('click') not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple `anchor` element like below:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com" class="foo">YahOO</a>
```

Below is JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".foo").trigger('click');
});
```

Why is the `click code` not getting executed?

http://jsfiddle.net/L7vaLrwk/

Comment: Have you tried it somewhere other than jsfiddle?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery how to trigger click event on href element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/jquery-how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element)

Comment: If you don't have an event handler assigned to the anchor there is nothing for jquery to trigger

Comment: `.trigger` doesn't trigger default behavior. Try something like `$(".foo")[0].click();` (not error proof). Actually, that is really not a good way to acheive what you want...

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this?  What are you trying to do?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `.trigger()` try using `.click()` and target the element by type and classname.

**HTML**

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com" class="foo">YahOO</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('a.foo')[0].click()
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way,

**HTML**
`<a href="http://www.example.com" class="foo" id="fooTest">YahOO</a>`

**JavaScript**
`document.getElementById('fooTest').click();`

Added an `id` to the link to uniquely identify it, and using plain javascript to simulate a click.
*Have replaced google.com with example.com as google doesn't open inside a iframe*

You can check working example here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/errhunter/k402g7p8/).

Comment: I downvoated because he asked how to target by class and do it with jQuery.  The HTML should have to change to answer the question.

Comment: @stefan, He tried with `jQuery`, but I can't see he mentioned of `jQuery` only solution.

Comment: Either way the html shouldn't need to change for the solution, you could have used `getElementsByClassName`