# Trigger click event to dynamically added link on href using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, href

I am dynamically creating the link on anchor tag through jquery, I want to trigger click event as soon as link gets attached to `href`, but in my case click event didn't get triggered.

**JQuery**:

```
$("#refShare").click(function(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: base_url+"create-refer",
        cache : false,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { email:email },  
        type:'post',
        success:function(response){
            jQuery('li#refShare a:first').attr("href", 'https://www.xyzLink.com/'+response.link);
            jQuery('li#refShare a:first').attr("target", 'blank');
            jQuery('li#refShare a:first').click();
       }); 
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
<li id="refShare">
<a href="" id="share-facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
</li>
<li>
    ....
</li>
    .....
</ul>
```

Comment: tried but it is not working

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was misleading (I deleted it). Do you reach the success callback? Can you `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: yes i'm getting link and it is getting attached but click event is not triggered as soon as link is attached

Comment: Does it work if you don't set the target (to blank)? Because of popup blockers of your browser.

Comment: or you can just do window.open('https://www.xyzLink.com/'+response.link, '_blank');

Comment: can you try `$("a").trigger("click")` as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5811251/912046

Comment: I think this could be a security behaviour of the browser. Probably the window.open() way is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try [trigger](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

`$("#refShare").trigger("click")`

Comment: Thanks but it is not working i tried this window.open('xyzLink.com/'+response.link, '_blank'); it is working

Comment: I hope you tried with the correct selector `$('li#refShare a:first').trigger("click");`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999806/how-to-trigger-click-event-on-href-element) might explain a bit.

Comment: @Kelsnare It is not true that `click()` does not trigger. In your linked documentation there is this: `Description: Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose the right element which can be clickable and your goal to redirect to somewhere else automatically(where human intervention does not require) can be achieved by using 'trigger' function.

you can do :

```
$('#share-facebook').trigger('click');
```

For further details/documentation about jquery 'trigger' function, you can check this url: [.trigger()](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Thanks but it is not working i tried this window.open('xyzLink.com/'+response.link, '_blank');  it is working

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Do you want an auto click or manual click?

If you want an auto => 
          jQuery('li#refShare a:first').trigger( "click" );
Otherwise manually means assign one id to this href and make it click.
         jQuery('li#refShare a:first').attr("id", 'some_id');

*outside Ajax*

```
  jQuery('#some_id').on('click','#some_id', function() {
    //do it your stuff...
 });
```

Comment: i want auto click i tried your code but it is not working

Comment: Best you analyze the jQuery.trigger(); this going to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


     setTimeout(function(){ 


      alert("Hello"); 

      jQuery('#Link_xyz').attr("href", 'https://github.com/gauravin213');
         jQuery('#Link_xyz').attr("target", 'blank');
         jQuery('#Link_xyz').click();



     }, 3000);


     jQuery(document).on('click', '#Link_xyz', function(){  

      var target = jQuery(this);

      var url = target.attr('href'); alert("click: "+url); 

      //window.open(url, '_blank');

            window.location.href = url;
     });

     

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
 <a id="Link_xyz" href="">Link</a>
</div>
```