# jQuery trigger('click') not going to href location

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to make the entire area of each li in a ul click to the `<a>` inside each li. Wordpress 5.41 (if that makes any difference.)

```
<ul class="six-corners">
  <li id="button_parents">
     <h3><a href="/parents">Parents</a></h3>
  </li>
  <li id="button_schools">
     <h3><a href="/schools">Schools</a></h3>
 </li>
```

etc...

And this jQuery:

```
jQuery(".six-corners li").click(function(event) { 
   if (! jQuery(event.target).is('a')) {
      var a = jQuery(this).find("a");
      a.trigger('click');
    }
});
```

What happens is that the 'a' appear to be clicked (the link flashes as though clicked), but the page doesn't actually go to the new location.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like you prevent default, which is definitely not seemed in your code, but when testing this in a JSFiddle everything worked ok...
Does jQuery loads well? Can you share a URL or test environment?

Comment: @Shalev Levi: How do I figure out where the preventDefault is coming from?

Comment: why are you trying those custom code? when you click a, then you can be redirected to other page. I can't understand. please provide more details.

Comment: As I said, because the users want to be able to click -anywhere- inside the <li> (each li has a very large image as a background)

Comment: Why don't you make the `<a>` a block element to fill the whole `<li>` and let browser do the redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar answer on SO, [How to trigger click event on href element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762745/2430549)
, and I found this summary most useful...

```
$('.cssbuttongo')[0].click();
                  ^
              Important!
```

For the most part, the problem is that `$('a')` will return an array of elements, and we want to click the first matching one, which we can solve by clicking on the `[0]`'th element.  Here, updated your code and made [**a working, online demo...**](https://jsbin.com/pularor/edit?html,js,output)

```
jQuery(".six-corners li").click(function(event) { 
   if (! jQuery(event.target).is('a')) {
      var a = jQuery(this).find("a");
      $(a)[0].click();            // Here I added [0],
                                  // to indicate that I am clicking the first element
    }
});
```

You can see I'm not calling `click()` on the `'a'`-selected elements, but on the `'a'[0]`'th selected element.  Now clicking on the link does work and opens the link as expected -- my browser properly 404's at the URL `https://null.jsbin.com/parents`, after I click `<h3><a href="/parents">Parents</a></h3>`.